# Parsing a long text string in Excel

Tags: excel, parsing, text, split

I have a column of text data in a csv file that looks something like this for each row:

{variable_1=result1, variable2=null, variable_three=result_3, variable_4=[{var4.1=result4.1, var4.2=result4.2, var4.3=result4.3}], variable_5=null}

I am trying to write some formulas to ultimately have the data look like this in Excel:

| raw data | variable_1 | variable2 | variable_three | var4.1 | var4.2 | var4.3 | variable_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {variable_1=result1, variable2=null, variable_three=result_3, variable_4=[{var4.1=result4.1, var4.2=result4.2, var4.3=result4.3}], variable_5=null} | result1 | null | result_3 | result4.1 | result4.2 | result4.3 | null |

The variable names will be the same for each run of the query that fetches this, but the results will vary in character length--which is why I formatted my example the way I did.  There is multiple rows of this too.

What's the best way to go about this??

Edit: There are approx 30  variables in my actual data

Comment: Have you tried Data: Text to Columns? Or left(), mid() right() with len() and find()?

Comment: @SolarMike I tried all of those, yes, but I spent a couple hours trying to make them work and decided I may be able to save some time if someone here with more experience doing this could help me out.  I know it's doable with those plus substitute(), but I'm just having trouble.

Comment: If it's in a CSV file, would you consider using, say, Python to generate the new fields before opening it in Excel? If so, can you be a bit more specific about the syntax of the value of a variable? It's not necessarily a number, right? Could it be a quoted string of some form?